# DefaultMemberAccess not found in Ognl 3.2.10

Tags: struts2, ognl

I have an application on latest struts 2.5.20 and OGNL 3.2.10.
Upon application startup, I got an exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ognl.DefaultMemberAccess
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
```

I checked on struts documentation and found the following

> [DefaultMemberAccess is only available in tests, it won't be used when there was no custom MemberAccess provided, an exception will be thrown in such case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzomx.png)

Here is the link to the document : [Release notes - version 3.2.3 - WIP](https://github.com/jkuhnert/ognl/blob/master/docs/VersionNotes.md#release-notes---version-323---wip-new-changes-are-coming)

I am unable to get any example or so that how can I create a Custom Implementation for MemberAccess and provide it to OgnlContext. Do anyone has idea how can I resolve this?

Comment: But this File is not included in OGNL 3.2.10.

Comment: please share your jar details.

Answer (score 1):

`DefaultMemberAccess` was removed after version `3.2.1`. You can degrade version to `3.2.1`,

This file was move to [here](https://github.com/jkuhnert/ognl/blob/master/src/test/java/ognl/DefaultMemberAccess.java).

You can refer to the project description in [README.md](https://github.com/jkuhnert/ognl)

> How to define an AccessMember?
>
> the best way is to implement your own AccessMember which will suite your project best, you can base on existing DefaultAccessMember and adjust it to your needs.